# Need a fast dataset 2D-viewer/plotter for large datasets

Tags: plot, dataset, large-data

I'm searching a data viewer/plotter for some data I've generated.

### Facts

First some facts about the data I've generated:

- There are several datasets with about 3 million data points each.
- Each dataset currently is stored in ascii format.
- Every line represents a point and consists of multiple columns.
- The first two columns determine the position of the point (i.e. x and y value) whereas the first column is a timestamp and the second is a normalized float between 0 and 1.
- The other columns contain additional data which may be used to colorize the plot or filter the data.
- An example data point:

> 2012-08-08T01:02:03.040 0.0165719281 foobar SUCCESS XX:1
>
> ### Current Approach

Currently I am generating multiple png files (with gnuplot) with different selection criteria like the following ones for each data set:

- Display all points in grey.
- Display all points in grey, but SUCCESS in red.
- Display all points in grey, but SUCCESS in red, XX:-1 in green; if both SUCCESS and XX:-1 match use blue as coloring.

### Drawbacks

With the current approach there are some drawbacks I'd like to have addressed:

- I can't easily switch on/off some filters or colorings because I have to generate a new png file every time.
- I need to use a limited resolution in my image file because the higher the resolution the slower is the viewer. So I can only zoom in to a limited level of detail.
- I don't have the raw data available in the png viewer for each point. Ideally I'd like to have the data visible on selection of a point.

### Already tested

I've already tested some other approaches:

- Gnuplot itself has a viewer but it can't handle that amount of points efficiently - it is too slow and consumes too much memory.
- I've had a quick look at KST, but I couldn't find a way to display 2D data and I don't think it will meet my wishes.

### Wishes

I'd like to have a viewer which can operate on the raw data, can displays the points quickly if zoomed out, can also zoom in quickly and as well should resolve the aforementioned drawbacks.

### Question

So finally, does anybody know of such a viewer or has another suggestion?
If there isn't a viewer some recommendations for programming it myself are welcome, too.

---

Thanks in advance
Stefan